# Passing Collection<SubClass> into a function expecting Collection<BaseClass> fails in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient way to cast List<SubClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082044/most-efficient-way-to-cast-listsubclass-to-listbaseclass)
>   [why polymorphism doesn't treat generic collections and plain arrays the same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770585/why-polymorphism-doesnt-treat-generic-collections-and-plain-arrays-the-same-way)

If I have an abstract base class `BaseClass` and I write a function expecting `Collection<BaseClass>` as its argument, calls to that function with a `Collection<SubClass>` of a class `SubClass extends BaseClass` fail to compile.

In the base class:

```
public void addLots(Collection<BaseClass> collection) {
    for(BaseClass yourbase : collection) {
        us.add(yourbase) //what you say!!
    }
}
```

And in the subclass:

```
public void addMoreLots(Collection<SubClass> collection) {
    addLots(collection); //FAILS TO COMPILE
}
```

Now I think I can see why this is: `Collection<SubClass>` is NOT a subclass of `Collection<BaseClass>`.  What is the *correct* method of making this call?

Comment: Thanks—I couldn't find it though, and I think this addresses a different question (more focused on "how do I do this", less focused on "why are arrays different than collections").  This presumable applies to any generic, for example `WeakReference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections` are **checked only during the compilation time**, `not` during the **run time**, so this is done in order to **protect a collection taking in the wrong type of object in.**

Try it this way...

`public <T extends BaseClass> void addLots(Collection<T> collection){ }`

**OR**

`public void addLots(Collection<? extends BaseClass> collection) {}`

Comment: I already worked it out and posted my own answer, but thank you :)

Comment: @AndrewWyld, nothing is more interesting and encouraging than finding an answer by ourself...... Keep it up... But please see i have mention both the ways to do it.....

Answer (score 2):

In a pinch, `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Collection<SubClass>)` can return a `Collection<BaseClass>`.  (It makes the collection unmodifiable, of course, but that's what makes it safe to treat a `Collection<SubClass>` as a `Collection<BaseClass>`.)

Answer (score 1):

`<? extends BaseClass>` should replace `<BaseClass>`.  The correct syntax for `addLots` is:

```
public void addLots(Collection<? extends BaseClass> collection) {
    for(BaseClass yourbase : collection) {
        us.add(yourbase) //what you say!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public void addLots(Collection<? extends BaseClass> collection) {
}
```

instead of

```
public void addLots(Collection<BaseClass> collection) {
}
```

which denotes a `Collection` of types which extends the base class can be a parameter.

Comment: I already worked it out, see below, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addLots(Collection<? extends BaseClass> collection) {
}
```

but with this you cannot call add to collection (i.e. you cannot do `collection.add()`),
but in this

```
public void addLots(Collection<? super SubClass> collection) {
}
```

you can call add (i.e. you can do `collection.add()`).