# Inheritance in Java with generics

Tags: java

Some days ago I was writing a simple Java program, and I discovered that this piece of code doesn't work (it gives a compile-time error):

```
ArrayList<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

where Document is an interface and Book implements Document.

Why inheritance in Java doesn't work with generics? If I want that code to work, I must use wildcards, like this:

```
ArrayList<? extends Document> docs = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

I was wondering what is the reason of this? If I need an ArrayList of Documents, and I know that a Book is also a Document, why can't I use an ArrayList of Books as an ArrayList of Documents?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770585/why-polymorphism-doesnt-treat-generic-collections-and-plain-arrays-the-same-way

Comment: Once you've combed through the answers as to why your first statement doesn't work, see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605337/646634) for an explanation of `extends` and `super` and what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just because the type of `List<U>` can't be a type a subtype of `List<V>` (unless U = V).

[image]

If you admit for example that `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<Number>`. You could write the following :

```
void addPi(List<Number> l) {
 l.add(3.14);
}

List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
addPi(l);
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think that there could be problems when adding new items.

Answer (score 7):

consider the following example:

```
ArrayList<Book>books = new ArrayList<Book>();
ArrayList<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Book>();
docs.add(new Document());
Book book = books.get(0); //Oops, now we have a variable of type book, referring to a Document that is not a book. Not good.
```

If you want more conceptual background material about this issue read up on [Covariance and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that if I use <? extends MyType> I can not add elements, but only read them.