# Polymorphism and ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, polymorphism

I have a class `Cell` and a class `Neighbour` extending `Cell`. But I get an error when I try to pass an `ArrayList<Neighbour>` to a function expecting an `ArrayList<Cell>`. What have I missed?

```
class Cell {
    PVector pos;

    Cell(PVector pPos) {
        pos = pPos.get();
    }
}

class Neighbour extends Cell {
    int borders = 0;

    Neighbour(PVector pPos) {
        super(pPos);
    }
}

private int inSet(PVector pPos, ArrayList<Cell> set) {
    [...]

    return -1;
}

[...]

ArrayList<Neighbour> neighbours = new ArrayList<Neighbour>();
PVector pPos = new PVector(0, 0);

[...]

inSet(pPos, neighbours);
```

The last line throws the error `The method iniSet(PVector, ArrayList) is not applicable for the arguments (PVector, ArrayList);

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This may help to understand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131664/inheritance-in-java-with-generics/17131699#17131699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because

```
List<A> != List<B> ... even if B extends A.
```

What you need to do is modify the function to the following

```
private int inSet(PVector pPos, ArrayList<? extends Cell> set) {
    [...]
    return -1;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
private int inSet(PVector pPos, List<? extends Cell> set)
```